# Run the "Before"-tagged hook only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am writing cucumber and capybara tests for a Rails application.
I have tagged some of the scenarios in different feature files with the tag "dependent".

I have written a hooks.rb file which is located under the support directory. I wanted to have the `if` block executed only once, even if I have multiple "dependent" tagged scenarios.

```
Before('@dependent') do
  $dunit ||= true  
  if $dunit then
    puts "Hey I am running now " 
    $dunit = false
  end 
end
```

In my case the Statement,

```
 puts "Hey I am running now "
```

...gets executed multiple times when I run multiple scenarios from multiple feature files with the "dependent" tag.

How I can have the `puts "Hey I am running now "` execute only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting the value of $dunit to true every time the block starts since false || true == true.  If you rewrite the block like below it should work

```
Before('@dependent') do
  $dunit ||= false
  return $dunit if $dunit
  puts "Hey I am runnig now " 
  $dunit = true
end
```